# Multiple whereKey:doesNotMatchKey:inQuery: in one query

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have users friendships sorted in a Friendship class with `fromUser` and `toUser` keys. When I want to only return users that are not in a friendship with the `currentUser`, I want to use two `whereKey:doesNotMatchKey:inQuery:` to sort the current friendships out.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"objectId" notEqualTo:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];
[query whereKey:@"username" hasPrefix:string];

PFQuery *fromFriends = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:parseFriendshipClassName];
[fromFriends whereKey:parseFriendshipFromUserKey equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
-> [query whereKey:@"objectId" doesNotMatchKey:parseFriendshipToUserIdKey inQuery:fromFriends];

PFQuery *toFriends = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:parseFriendshipClassName];
[toFriends whereKey:parseFriendshipToUserKey equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
-> [query whereKey:@"objectId" doesNotMatchKey:parseFriendshipFromUserIdKey inQuery:toFriends];
```

If I comment out either of these two lines, the other one works as expected, but if they are both there, only the last of them works.

In the Friendship table, the users are referenced both as a pointer and as their `objectId`. I use the `objectId` to reference them here, so it is not because I compare pointers to ids.

The documentation does not seem to suggest, that adding more than one would override the old one.

Is this expected behaviour? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score -1):

In this case you should use  the `orQueryWithSubqueries:`. It should solve this.

Comment: How would that help? What I am trying to do is a AND query and not an OR. I am comparing two different keys in the two subqueries.